# Avoid exporting singleton in es6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

As I have seen, ES6 exports singletons for object literals:

```
// module A
export const singleton = {
  user: 'a',
  asd: 'b'
}

setTimeout(() => console.log(singleton.user), 5000) // 'asd'

// module B
import { singleton } from './A'
singleton.user = 'asd'
```

ie: if I change the A exports in B, it's also changed in A and in all modules that import A
So, I wanted A to export a new instance of the object instead of a singleton, and I did this:

```
// module A
export const getObject = () => ({ user: 'asd', asd: 'b' })
```

That works, but I was thinking, is there a cleaner way to export new instances? Or the only way is exporting that function that I should call in B to get my new instance?

I think I can do this too, but it doesn't convince me:

```
// module A
export const getObject = (() => ({ user: 'asd', asd: 'b' }))()
```

Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with using the factory function?

Comment: What about [freezing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) `singleton`?

Comment: @sp00m - The op wants a new instance of the object each time.  Freezing does not achieve that.

Comment: @jfriend00 Just in case of an XY problem where the original issue would that B shouldn't be allowed to modify A, as OP said "B can modify A, so I started exposing a function instead".

Comment: If you want a new instance in every module that imports `A`, exporting a factory function from `A` will be the best way.

Comment: I ended up freezing because it works for my use case and if I need a new instance I use Object.assign({}, freezedObj). Thanks.

Comment: @LucasJanon Just for your information, the past participle of "freeze" is "frozen", so your variable should be named `frozenObj` ;)

Comment: lol, seems that I should watch more Disney movies and stop thinking about singletons to improve my variables naming :p

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ES module is evaluated only once on first import, this efficiently makes module exports singletons.

```
export const getObject = () => ({ user: 'asd', asd: 'b' })
```

is factory function and it's perfectly valid in this case, it's preferable for data-only object that has no inheritance and no methods.

A class is a suitable alternative (a bit less efficient than factory function but a better choice if there are methods):

```
export class A {
  constructor() {
    this.user =  'asd';
    this.asd = 'b';
  }
}
```

Since React is in use, it's safe to assume that the code is transpiled with Babel, so [class fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) proposal can be used. They aren't available in ES6 and provide syntactic sugar for constructor code listed above:

```
export class A {
  user = 'asd';
  asd = 'b';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When a module is loaded, it is cached.  So, when someone else loads it again, no new code is run.  The previous exports are just returned.

> That works, but I was thinking, is there a cleaner way to export new instances? Or the only way is exporting that function that I should call in B to get my new instance?

If you want a new instance each time, you have to export a function that you can call to get a new instance.  There is no other way because loading a previously loaded module does not run any additional code - it just returns the previous cached exports.

You can either export a factory function (like in your example):

```
export const myFactory = function() {
   return { user: 'asd', asd: 'b' };
}
```

Or you can export a constructor function (that the caller would call with `new` to get a new object).

```
export class myObj {
   constructor() {
       this.user = 'asd';
       this.asd = 'b';
   }
   checkUser() {
       // some code here that operates on instance data
   }
}
```

Either the factory function or the constructor function would work just fine.  If there are no methods and you just want a plain object, then the factory function is simpler.  If there are methods, then the class probably makes more sense.