# Doesn't ES module system guarantee module singleton?

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

Let's suppose we have a dependency module graph where more than one module import another at once, something like that: `(A) ---> (B) <--- (C)`

It seems the ECMAScript specification doesn't guarantee both `A` and `C` would get the same instance of an object represents the `B` module (or its exported entity).

To wit: a JS module is represented by an instance of specification object called [`Abstract Module Record`](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-abstract-module-records) (its concrete version is [`Source Text Module Record`](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-source-text-module-records)). An object of this type, in particular, stores bindings for the module (that is, declared variable names with their corresponding values). In the other words, different `Module Record`s have different bindings (it's a pretty simple idea because it's the reason we tend to use modules).

Before code evaluating, a `Module Record` [`Link()`](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-moduledeclarationlinking) method is executed and it, in turn, recursively calls the [`InitializeEnvironment()`](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-source-text-module-record-initialize-environment) on each of graph `Module Record`s. The aim of `InitializeEnvironment()` is to create bindings for every imported module. To obtain the needed `Module Record` which would represent one of them, this function uses [`HostResolveImportedModule()`](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-modules). It receives as its argument `referencingScriptOrModule` (an importing module, that is `A` or `C`) and a string `specifier` (something like `b.js`).

There is the bottom line starts to appear.

> Each time this operation is called with a specific
> `referencingScriptOrModule`, `specifier` pair as arguments it must return
> the same `Module Record` instance if it completes normally.

I can't draw from this excerpt there is a guarantee `A` and `C` will get the same instance of `Module Record` represents `B` in due to `(A, "b.js")` and `(C, "b.js")` are not the same pairs.

Does it all mean, in effect, the ES module system doesn't guarantee a possibility to create a module singleton? There is a good few of advice to export a singleton entity from a module. [It is said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51180419/5006880) a module is evaluated once and then cached, so it's an acceptable way to deal with singletons. However, although the statement about caching is true, but still this fact per se doesn't entail an module system impementation would resolve to the same imported module for *different* importing ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is no guarantee in ECMAScript - the rules for how to resolve module specifiers are determined by the host.

> Multiple different `referencingScriptOrModule`, `specifier` pairs may
> map to the same *Module Record* instance. **The actual mapping
> semantic is implementation-defined** but typically a normalization
> process is applied to specifier as part of the mapping process. A
> typical normalization process would include actions such as alphabetic
> case folding and expansion of relative and abbreviated path
> specifiers.

So only your host (like node.js or the browser) will give you the guarantee that it will always resolve certain specifiers to the **same** module.

There are many examples where `(A, "b.js")` and `(C, "b.js")` *should* not resolve to the same module - e.g. when `A` is *one/a.js*, it should return the module *one/b.js*, while `C` might be *two/c.js* and result in the module *two/b.js*.

Comment: It's curious the spec by no means sets a connection between OS files and `Module Record`s, so it's even possible to resolve two paths to different files to one single `Module Record` (at least I can't find restrictions on it)

Comment: @Mergasov Might be related to the fact that not all module loaders will work with OS files :-)