# When we export new Foo() in JavaScript, by what rule do we know it is a singleton? (if we use webpack)

Tags: javascript

I often see code

```js
export default Foo;
```

and `Foo` can be a function or a class, but if we do

```js
export default new Foo();
```

I was told that it should be a singleton when *multiple files* in the project all do

```js
import Foo from './Foo';
```

and it will be the same exact object, meaning that it'd be a singleton, but by what rule do we know it is instantiated once instead of instantiated multiple times?

I think the standard answer is that there is no guarantee, but what if we use webpack (or some other tool), can we know it is guaranteed to be only one?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Doesn't ES module system guarantee module singleton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67270619/doesnt-es-module-system-guarantee-module-singleton)

Comment: are you sure that question is the same as this one... I don't quite see an answer there

Comment: Pretty sure, yes - the answer it gives you is that there is no such rule, an implementation _may_ give different importers of your module different instances of Foo and still be spec-compliant.

Comment: @nonopolarity [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67274577) states that there is no such guarantee based on the spec. It's implementation-dependant.

Comment: so would that mean if it is webpack... it can be guaranteed just one?

Answer (score -1):

```js
export default new Foo();
```

is same as:

```js
const foo = new Foo();
export default foo;
```

As the module runs, 1 instance of Foo is created. That instance is being exported, so everyone who import it gets the same instance.

If you want to check that they are exactly the same, write 2 modules which import `foo` then have 1 of these modules pass its `foo` to the other via a function and do a comparison via `===` operator.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="module" src="foo.js"></script>
        <script type="module" src="mod1.js"></script>
        <script type="module" src="mod2.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

foo.js:

```js
export default {};
```

mod1.js:

```js
import myFoo from './foo.js';

export function mod1Func(other_foo) {
   console.log('same?', other_foo === myFoo);
}
```

mod2.js:

```js
import myFoo from './foo.js';
import { mod1Func } from './mod1.js';

mod1Func(myFoo);
```

And it should print:

```
same? true
```

Comment: I think the question is, how do we know the two above are the same... could we also argue that `export` is run every time it is reached?

Comment: @FZs that doesn't mean that *the module* will not run multiple times.

Comment: @VLAZ You're right. I've just read the proposed dupe target where it talks about this... Until now, I lived with the misbelief that a single module will *always* be executed only once during the execution of a program.

Comment: @FZs TBH, me too.

Comment: So I read the post referenced by @jonrsharpe. Interesting spec. However even the answer gave an example where having 2 modules in different path "directories" import the same module "specifier" yields different modules. Have yet to see a real case where importing the same resolved module via even different specifiers result in the module imported twice or more. Even the spec says typical action would be to normalise and resolve relative paths. I guess it's up to individuals how much they want to make assumptions given the spec.