# Javascript imports, do they duplicate?

Tags: javascript, import, bundler, code-splitting

I'm trying to find a javascript workflow solution to bundle my code in multiple files. I have a question I can't find the answer, maybe it's under my eyes but well...

If I use javascript import in a JS file for functionalities, that will be bundle into one JS file.

```js
import anime from "animejs";

class Functionality1 {
  // some code using animeJs
}

export let functionality1 = new Functionality1();
```

```js
import anime from "animejs";

class Functionality2 {
  // some code using animeJS
}

export let functionality2 = new Functionality2();
```

So at the end, I have 2 bundled files functionality1.js and functionality2.js. But both import animeJS library. If they are called on the same page, is AnimeJS called twice two ?

- If yes, if there any way to avoid this behavior ?
- If no, can you explain it to me ?

Thank you

Comment: No there singletons by nature.   IOW:  If say you put `console.log('init')` inside `animejs` you will see the log only once, no matter how many times you import it.  So in your example above, you will only also ever have once instance of `functionnality1 / 2`

Comment: @Keith "*No there singletons by nature.*" weirdly, that's not the case. I *also* thought that was the case but recently I found that [Bergi quoted the relevant part of the spec here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67274577/) and it doesn't actually *guarantee* singleton behaviour. Although, I'm certainly not aware of any implementation that doesn't give you singletons. Seems all the current ones do. But theoretically possible a different module loader wouldn't.

Comment: "If they are called on the same page, is AnimeJS called twice two ?" <-- animejs is *called* when the instances you export from these two modules are called. What you probably wanted to ask is if an imported module's code is run every time the module is imported - to which @Keith 's answer is correct, it's only run once, they're singletons.

Comment: @VLAZ  Isn't that link how how modules are resolved, not on how they act when resolved.?   That's how I read it anyway..   I would think any modules loader that didn't singleton has the potential to break a lot of libs..

Comment: @Keith how they behave afterwards depends on how they are resolved. Let's say you have `let x = 0; export const counter = () => x++;` in module `A`. If modules `B` and `C` use `import {counter} from "A"` then you *might* get a series of completely unique numbers generated accoss `B` and `C`. Or you might have one stream of digits in `B` that starts with zero and another stream of digits in `C` which also starts at zero. Again, to the best of my knowledge, the latter doesn't happen right now. But it is a possibility.

Comment: @Keith RE: "*I would think any modules loader that didn't singleton has the potential to break a lot of libs..*" yes, I think so, too. I think we all expect singleton behaviour because it makes sense. AMD/UMD technologies before ES6 did have singletons, so the behaviour is grounded. Seems like ES6 spec just left this deliberately open for implementations. I can't really think of a good reason to *not* have singletons. Maybe some academic code or something that is *very* specialised.